# {Excel} How to create Username & Password for sheets without CODING

Tags: excel

I want to create a login to each sheet without coding. (Excel File)

I tried with VBA,

but my company is restricting using macros.

because of that I'm trying to look for a method to do the same but without macros.

Please, help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can protect the workbook against reading or modifying. However, it will be controlled by a password. The password against modification can relatively easily be removed. The password protecting against reading cannot easily be removed as the file is encrypted using this password or it's hash thereof.

The proper way to protect the Excel workbook is to put it on a shared folder with controlled access using access control list. You need to have a Windows domain in place. The network admin will be responsible to secure these resources.